# Super Crate Box keeps crashing

Tags: steam, windows-8.1, super-crate-box

Whenever I start Super Crate Box, everything works fine at first.  After about 3 minutes though, the game crashes.

Any help?

---

I downloaded the game from Steam, and the version I'm using is for Windows.

I have an Intel i5 core with 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running Windows 7, 8, or 10?

If you're running Windows 8, check out this video:

which worked for me, and also this zip file associated with the video: http://www.mediafire.com/download/tc0w7jee24s44u6/supercrateboxwin8.zip.

Other than that, check to make sure your graphics card meets minimum system requirements, which you can find on SCB's steam page: http://store.steampowered.com/app/212800/

MINIMUM:

OS:Windows XP

Processor:1.2 Ghz

Memory:512 MB RAM

DirectX®:8.0

Hard Drive:100 MB HD space

Oh yeah, I forgot to mention to check to make sure you have DirectX 8 installed

1. Download and extract the zip file
2. Navigate to your program files x86 / Steam / steamapps / Common / supercratebox / supercratebox.exe
3. Rename supercratebox.exe to supercratebox.exe.old
4. Place the new .exe file in the same folder
5. Run again and play the game